# How to turn std::string length into hex and than back into string?

Tags: c++, string, boost, stl, hex

So... I want to create simple [HTTP Chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding#Encoded_response) prototype. I have messages as std::strings. And my server API is all string based... so I wonder how to turn std::string length into hex and than back into string?

So say we had `std::string("This is the data in the first chunk\r\n").length()` that would return say int `37`. I want to convert it into hex `0x25` and than to get out from that hex `std::string("25")`. How to do such thing (using stl and boost)?

Comment: You don't know to convert an integer into hexadecimal? Then how can you even think that you can work with HTTP or any network protocol for that matter?

Comment: @Nawaz: by learning, one step at a time.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: That is definitely the way. But it doesn't seem so from OP's post, or you didn't understand what I meant in my previous comment. I mean what if I say I want to design and write my own OS, when I don't know anything about programming?

Comment: @Nawaz: and what if you don't say that, but instead you say something entirely reasonable and that has a short answer? For example, how to convert an integer to a hex string in C++. Maybe the questioner has a reasonable amount of experience with networking, but doesn't know the bizarre details of C++ stream formatting.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes. That makes sense if you say that only. But you say that "I want to design and write my own OS, but I don't know *how to convert an integer to a hex string in C++*?", then you will get same comments which I made. Also, converting a decimal integer into hexadecimal one has nothing do with C++ stream. One can do without it. Plus, if one doesn't know C++ stream; then he doesn't know C++, and so he *first* needs to know it in order to work with it, for which he needs some introductory book.

Comment: @Nawaz: Who's trying to design and write their own OS? The OP wants to create something quite simple, and is missing some knowledge of a rather arcane part of the C++ library.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Again, converting a decimal integer into hexadecimal integer has nothing to do with C++ library or stream.

Comment: @Nawaz: let's put it another way - personally I had written one HTTP client and contributed to another before I knew any C++ at all (no servers, though, unless you count 20 lines of Java to serve a few files with no frills). I just didn't write them in C++. So I don't see any contradiction there. That said, the question might contain a fairly serious misconception -- it says "I want to convert (the int) to hex, and then convert that hex to string". There's no such thing as an integer being "hex" or "decimal", only string representations have those bases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // To string:

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::hex << 37;
    std::string result = oss.str();

    std::cout << result << '\n';

    // Back from string (if you need it):

    std::istringstream iss(result);
    int original;
    if (!(iss >> std::hex >> original)) {
        // handle error here
    } else {
        std::cout << original << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << std::hex << your_number;
```

`buffer.str()` will now give you a hex-representation of your number; If you want the `0x` before the number, use this:

```
buffer << std::hex << showbase << your_number;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::ostringstream str;
str << "0x" << std::hex << length;

std::string result = str.str();
```

Demonstrated [here](http://ideone.com/lhecj).

Answer (score 1):

Stringstreams are one way:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << "0x" << std::hex << 12345;
std::string aString = ss.str();
```

An alternative is the all-mighty `boost::format`.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a solution:

```
std::string convert_length_to_hex(const std::string& str)
{
    std::ostringstream result;
    result << std::hex << str.length();
    return result.str();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example of dec to hex conversion and then back

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>   

std::string dec2hex(int dec){
    std::string result;    
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << dec;
    ss >> result;
    std::transform(result.begin(), result.end(), result.begin(), ::toupper);
    return result;}

int hex2dec(std::string& hex){
    int x;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << hex;
    ss >> x;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    std::string hex = "ABCD";
    int dec = hex2dec(hex);
    std::cout << dec << std::endl;
    std::cout << dec2hex(dec) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```